# counting loops?

Tags: c++

i was creating a seating program and i was wonder if there was a way to count the loops and place it in a variable. im trying to let the user know how many tickets he purchased

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <istream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

const int numberOfRow = 15;
const int numberOfCol = 20;
void print(char matrix[][20],int numberOfRow, int numberOfCol);


int main()
{ 
    ifstream datafile;
    int i, j;
    char matrix[numberOfRow][numberOfCol], seat[numberOfRow][numberOfCol];
    char option;
    int row, col, totalsold;
    float totSold, temp,price = 0 , ticketprice[numberOfRow], totRevenue;
    bool another = true;
    string filename;
    datafile.open("c:\\price.dat"); 

    for(i=0;i<numberOfRow;++i)
    { 
        datafile >> temp;
        ticketprice[i]=temp;
        cout<< "Row ";
        cout<< setw(2)<< fixed << setprecision(2)<< i << setw(7) << ticketprice[i]<< endl;
    }

    for(i = 0; i< numberOfRow; i++)
        for(j = 0; j< numberOfCol; j++)
            matrix[i][j] = '*';

    print(matrix,numberOfRow, numberOfCol);

    while(another)
    {
        totalsold = 0;
        totRevenue = 0; 
        cout << "Please enter the row you would like to sit in: " << endl;
        cin >> row;
        cout << "Please enter the column you would like to sit in: " << endl;
        cin >> col;
        cout << "would you like to purchase more tickets? <y,n>" << endl;
        cin >> option;
        matrix[row][col] = '#';
        /*totRevenue = totRevenue + ticketprice[row];*/


        if(option == 'y' || option == 'Y')
        {
            another = true;
        }

        else 
        {
            another = false;
            print(matrix,numberOfRow, numberOfCol);
            totRevenue = totRevenue + ticketprice[row];
        }
    }

    totRevenue = totRevenue + ticketprice[row];
    cout << "Total Tickets Sold: " << endl;// << totSold << endl;
    cout << "Total Revenue: $ " << fixed << setprecision(2)<< totRevenue<< endl;
    cin >> i;
    cin.get();
    return 0;

}
void print(char matrix[][20],int numberOfRow, int numberOfCol)
{
    int row, col, i, j;

    cout << "seat:   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19"<< endl;
    for(i = 0; i < numberOfRow; i++)
    {
        cout << "row" << setw(3)<< i;
        for(j = 0; numberOfCol > j; j++)
            cout << setw(3) << matrix[i][j];

        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think the average non-programmer would understand "Please enter the column you would like to sit in:" !

Comment: "count the loops"? explain, please.

Comment: well i wish to show the user how many time he purchased the ticket

Comment: Unsolicited advice: `totSold` and `totalsold` variable names are asking for trouble. You're bound to get them confused eventually. Also, `matrix` seems an uninspired name for the arena layout. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure about your while loop ?

Something like this, would make more sens:

```
//...

int totalsold = 0;
float totRevenue = 0.0;

while(another)
{
    cout << "Please enter the row you would like to sit in: " << endl;
    cin >> row;
    cout << "Please enter the column you would like to sit in: " << endl;
    cin >> col;
    cout << "would you like to purchase more tickets? <y,n>" << endl;
    cin >> option;
    matrix[row][col] = '#';

    ++totalsold; // increment the number of tickets sold
    totRevenue += ticketprice[row]; // increment to total price of the tickets

    if(option == 'n' || option == 'N')
    {
        another = false; // exit the loop
    }
}

print(matrix,numberOfRow, numberOfCol); 
cout << "Total Tickets Sold: " << totalsold << endl;
cout << "Total Revenue: $ " << fixed << setprecision(2)<< totRevenue<< endl;

//...
```

However, there is plenty of strange things in the provided code. But the most important is to keep practicing, so keep playing with the code and those strange things will disappear like magic with experience ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count the number of tickets bought, you should define a variable that contain the number of bought tickets and increment it right after `another = true;`.

```
if(option == 'y' || option == 'Y')
{
    another = true;
    ++totSold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you're looking for is a line like:

```
totSold += 1;
```

immediately after assigning `#` to the arena layout.

Note that you should check if the seat is sold already or not before selling it again. :)